# Produce SocketTimeoutException in Junit Tests in Netty

Tags: netty, socket-timeout-exception

**Problem**

I need to test a scenario where my Netty Server will throw SocketTimeoutExceptions causing the client to retry on those failures and eventually fail.I want to achieve this with integration testing in Junit Java

**Things I tried**

I tried exploiting SO_TIMEOUT = 0 for both option and child option and at the same time keeping SO_KEEPALIVE = false and SO_BACKLOG = 0 . Also I reduced CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS to 0. But nothing has worked. Client is still able to connect to the server.**

**Sample code below**

```
 ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap()
                    .group(NativeTransportUtil.newEventLoopGroup(),       NativeTransportUtil.newEventLoopGroup())
.channel(NativeTransportUtil.serverSocketChannelClass())
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 0)
                    .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, false)
                    .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 0)
                    .childOption(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 0)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 0)
                    .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 0)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_TIMEOUT, 0)
                    .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_TIMEOUT, 0)
                    .childHandler(new NewConnectionInitializer());

            bootstrap.bind(port).syncUninterruptibly();

            client.sendSync(request);
```

**Results**

Actual Result : The above code results in a successful connection from the client to the server.

ExpectedResult : I want the server to throw out SocketTimeoutException.